# if value exist in table loop query until it does't

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I need to make an while loop that checks if $key is in database, if it is make a new key and check again. It seems like an easy part of code but i cant get it to work.

I've been Googling and trying different solutions for hours but no luck.

```
$key = 'aa';//RandomString(30);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = '$key'");

$j = 1;
while(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
    $key = 'aa'.$j;//RandomString(30);
    $j++;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to include the `mysql_query();` inside the `while` loop. The way you are currently doing it you are checking the same results every time the mysql database is only being queried once.

```
$key = 'aa';//RandomString(30);

$j = 1;
$found = true;
while($found == true){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = '$key'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
        $found = false;
    } else {
        $key = 'aa'.$j;//RandomString(30);
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Fyi, `mysql_` functions are deprecated so you should try to migrate to mysqli or pdo.

Also this would become inefficient if you had a lot of entries starting with `aa` in this situation. It may be better to find all entries that start with `aa` then find the last one and increment the number by one. That way you could do it with one query instead of possibly hundreds or thousands.

Comment: Thankyou, I had tried this without the if statement and therefor only looped 2 times. But now it works!

The reason im still using mysql is because im forceded.